# How to get "pass parameter"

Tags: vb6

I developed one vb6 exe file. I called it from run menu of window "C:\file1.exe -console". I don't know how to pass  "-console" in my program. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: if it is really VB6 and you want to get, not pass, an argument then you need to look at the commandline, which can be gotten from `Command`

Comment: guys like voted down.lol

Comment: Your question was most likely voted down because this is a very basic question, easily answered and easily found with a simple search. That you asked this indicates you did no research on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    If Command <> "" Then
        MsgBox Command
    End If

End Sub
```

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262696%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)